# How to change the library mode in Dotfuscator using post-build event command line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, command-line, dotfuscator

I'm trying to obfuscate a c# project using Dotfuscator CE tool which comes along with Visual Studio 2010, with the help of following commands I managed to obfuscate the code.

[image]

but it doesn't make any changes to the private or public method names, I knew that by changing the 'Library mode' which comes under Assemblies-->Properties, I should be able to rename the functions.

[image]

but I do not know how to include the library property within the post build event command line. Could somebody please help..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the help text of the dofuscator command line:

```
Extended Options:
        /in:[+|-]<file>[,[+|-]<file>]                : specify input assemblies. Use prefix to obfuscate input as public(+) or private(-) assembly, use : after the filename to specify a package type
```

So, by default just doing `/in:foo.exe` would mean `foo.exe` is treated as not being in library mode. To obfuscate it in library mode instead, use the `+` symbol like so `/in:+foo.exe`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, very useful to me, just a quick one, what does /in:-foo.exe mean..? is this gonna uncheck the library mode property...?

Comment: @San yes, it defaults to "off" on the command line so `/in:foo.exe` and `/in:-foo.exe` do the exact same thing at the moment.

Comment: Cheers again for the quick reply...:)

Answer (score 0):

Eartz,

You are partially right, library mode is disabled by default for exe's, but dll's are the opposite. If you look at San' original post you can clearly see he is obfuscating a dll, hence his issue.

Comment: This is a comment on an answer ... please post it as such when you are able.